# Sorting a struct list of struct

Tags: c++, list, sorting, struct

I have two structs:

```
struct memBlock {
    uint32_t  pid;
    uint32_t  moduleSize;
    void*  moduleStart;
};

struct memory{
    uint32_t  memSize;
    uint32_t  memSizeOS;
    uint32_t  chunkSize;
    uint32_t  nextFit;
    list<memBlock> freeMem;
    list<memBlock> usedMem;
};

memory memo;
```

I want to sort the freeMem list of memo in ascending order of moduleSize.

How can I accomplish this?

I tried this:

```
sort( memo.freeMem.begin( ), memo.freeMem.end( ), 
                []( const memory& a, const memory&b ){
                return a.freeMem < b.freeMem;
            } );
```

but I don't know how to specify that sort should consider moduleSize variable.

Solution:

```
memo.freeMem.sort([]( memBlock a,memBlock b){return a.moduleSize<b.moduleSize;});
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you want something like this:

```
sort( memo.freeMem.begin( ), memo.freeMem.end( ), 
   []( const memblock& a, const memblock&b ){
   return a.moduleSize < b.moduleSize;
} );
```